# Adding a new row Using SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, insert

I'm learning how to use SQL Server Management Studio and can't figure out how to insert a new row into a table.

Table Structure:

```
ID,
Field1,
Field2
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Field1,Field2) VALUES(1,2)
```

Error:

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25503

I'm probably missing something very simple.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The insert syntax is right (assuming your table isn't named 'Table', I can see that causing issues).  What is the entire table structure (data types, nullability, keys)?  I almost wonder about checking for database corruption..

Comment: Is your table _actually called_ Table? If so, try `INSERT INTO [Table]...`. If not, please post the real code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I was on the verge of pulling out all of my hair, and it appears using single quotes instead of double quotes fixed the problem.

Now, I want to pull my hair out even more.

Thanks for the replies everyone.  This one was my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Does your table have an auto-incrementing `ID` field?  If not, you will need to manually specify the value for the `ID` in your `INSERT` statement.

You can check if the `ID` field is auto-incrementing by using the Object Explorer, navigating to the table and expanding the Columns node.  Find the `ID` column, right-click on it and select **Properties**.  If the Identity property is set to **False** it means that the `ID` field is NOT auto-incrementing.

Your other option for adding a row to the table is to navigate to the table in Object Explorer, right clicking on it and selecting **Open Table**.  You can then go to the last row in the grid and manually enter the values for the columns.

Comment: ID is set as the primary key, and identity, with the identity seed and increment set to 1.  Based on my understanding of this software, this is the equivalent of specifying an auto increment. So that is why I do not specify the ID explicitly.

Comment: Try adding a row through the Open Table process as I describe in my edited post.  Do you get the same error?  Also - what are the field types for Field1 and Field2?  Are you sure they're numeric fields?  If not you'll need to surround the values you're adding with quotes.

Comment: When I navigate to the table, there are two folders: Columns and Indexes.  I don't see the option to view the whole table.

Comment: Right-click on the actual table name and there should be an option to open the table.  I'm using SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 might call it something slightly different.

Comment: These are the options I see:

Edit Tables
Properties
Delete
Reports > Custom Reports
Refresh

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  Maybe I'm using the wrong software?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is the right software.  Maybe it's a permissions problem.  You're only seeing some of the options that I have in my database.  Do you have the right permissions to be able to view the table data?